# My organisation has blocked the ngrok, is there any other way to connect bot emulator with teams channel without ngrok in local?

Tags: botframework, ngrok

I am looking for ngrok alternative to connect the bot emulator with the Teams channel to test locally

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Azure Service Bus Relay [option](https://github.com/gabog/AzureServiceBusBotRelay). Once you have it built and configured it works similarly to ngrok. For most situations, it should meet your needs.

Comment: FYI, I typed up the README for this so I can help in setting up. However, I had nothing to do with the development. If you run into an issue, you will need create an issue for the developer to respond to.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info. I did the setup as per the instructions. I've received 401 unauthorized error in the bot emulator. POST401directline.conversationUpdate

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also use NPM PACKAGE "**localtunnel**" if you are looking for an ngrok alternative.
From Above you can access it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel